# Sort using MongoEngine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

How do I sort the query objects in MongoEngine, like I would in a regular mongodb query?

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Mongoengine is inspired by Django's ORM, and like Django, it uses [`order_by`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=order_by#ordering) to sort the result set. `order_by` takes a variable number of string arguments, which are the field names (as defined in your documents) optionally preceded by a "`-`" (to indicate a descending sort, i.e. highest first).

For example:

```
class Person(Document):
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    age = IntField()

# later
people = Person.objects.order_by('last_name', '-age')
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! for whatever reason I couldn't find that in the docs

Comment: `order_by` link update: http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=order_by#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: Good answer but the link is broken

Comment: In the last line of the example, `Person.objects` must be `Person.objects()`

Comment: You have not specified the web framework you are using. In case it is Django, you can use the Django ORM directly with Mongodb instead of using Mongoengine by using the [djongo connection](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)

Comment: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: Also, use '-' for descending and '+' for ascending: something like ``Post.objects.order_by("-created_date")`` would return the entries with most recent first.