# How to sort MongoDB results with MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, mongoengine

I'm just learning how to use MongoDB by using MongoEngine from Python. Simply getting all users is done as follows:

```
User.objects
```

I now want to order the users on their creation date. In the MongoDB docs I found [something about .sort()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/), but in the [MongoEngine docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/) I can't find anything about sort. I also tried using the following:

```
User.objects.sort('created')
```

but this leads to an `AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'sort'`.

So does anybody know how I can sort MongoDB results using MongoEngine? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

[Sort using MongoEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315720/sort-using-mongoengine)

The function is order_by, not sort. The hyphen sets direction.