# How to apply "sort" on embedded document in django mongodb engine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I am using **django-mongodb-engine**.

I have example data as below:

```
{
    "name":[{"first_name":"rajat","last_name":"verma"},{"first_name":"jay","last_name":"patil"},]
}
```

Now I want to apply sorting on first_name field.  I tried to search on google and also looked django-mongodb-engine library. But there is no solution.

Does django-mongodb-engine supports sorting? IS there any solution? Even any  little suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320311/2555504) should answer you.

Answer is `order_by`. it can be used to sort for mongodb too.

Here are the [docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=order_by#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.order_by)

Comment: Thanks, But I need two level embedded field sorting like
people = Person.objects.order_by('name__first_name') Which is not supported by django with *django-mongodb-engine*   I am not using mongoengine